# sed match a pattern and insert newline followed by replacement text

Tags: awk, sed, newline, text-processing

Let's say my input file `es-service` has the following lines:

> ```
> # Comment 1
> key1=value1
>
> # Comment 3
> key3=value3
> ```

If the pattern `key2=value2` is not present in the above file, then add it after `key1=value1`

Hence, the file should now have:

> ```
> # Comment 1
> key1=value1
>
> # Comment 2
> key2=value2
>
> # Comment 3
> key3=value3
> ```

I came up with the following to achieve it:

```
if ! grep -qxF 'key2=value2' es-service;
  then sed -i "/key1/a \n# Comment 2\nkey2=value2" es-service
fi
```

The problem is the first `\n` after `/a` doesn't insert a new-line. Hence I end-up getting the below:

```
key1=value1
n# Comment 2
key2=value2
```

instead of

```
key1=value1

# Comment 2
key2=value2
```

**Edit**:
I eventually solved it by adding one more sed to match `Comment 2` and add a `newline` before it by using option `i`.

```
if ! grep -qxF 'key2=value2' es-service;
  then sed -i "/key1/a \n# Comment 2\nkey2=value2" es-service; sed -i '/# Comment 2/i\ ' es-service 
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

All in a `awk` using loop

```
awk '/key2=/ {f=1} /key1=/ {n=NR} {a[NR]=$0} END {for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) {print a[i];if(i==n && !f) print "\n# Comment 2\nkey2=value2"}}' file
# Comment 1
key1=value1

# Comment 2
key2=value2

# Comment 3
key3=value3
```

- `/key2=/ {f=1}` if `key2=` is found set flag `f` to prevent double insertion.
- `/key1=/ {n=NR}` if `key1` is found, store the line number in `n`
- `a[NR]=$0` store all line in array `a`
- `END` After file is rund, do:
- `for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)` loop trough all line, then
- - `print a[i]` print the line and
- - `if(i==n && !f)` if line is where `key=1` is found and flag `f` is not true, do:
- - - `print "\n# Comment 2\nkey2=value2"` print extra information.

Comment: @SandeepKanabar added info.  But take care if file is were large, it may slow down due to storing all line in an array.

Comment: Agree which is why was looking to do using `sed`.

Comment: @SandeepKanabar if `key2` need to come after `key1` and not elsewhere in the file, it can be down without loop. But if its random location, you need to test the whole file first.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, this code will take care of any missing key(if keys are NOT continuous in their sequence and add them with comment number too).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="="
}
!NF{
  print
  next
}
/^# Comment/{
  val=$0
  next
}
/^key/{
  first_col=$1
  sub(/[a-zA-Z]+/,"",first_col)
  while(first_col!=prev+1){
     prev++
     print "# Comment "prev ORS "key"prev"=value"prev ORS
  }
  prev=first_col
  print val ORS $0
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: @Sandeep Kanabar, I tried with a generic approach, could you please check this and let me know if this helps you?

Answer (score 1):

A `gnu awk` solution without loop

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR>1 && a~/key1/ && !/key2/ {print "# Comment 2\nkey2=value2"} 1; {a=$0}' file
# Comment 1
key1=value1

# Comment 2
key2=value2

# Comment 3
key3=value3
```

- `-v RS= -v ORS='\n\n'` Set Record selector to nothing and output record selector to two new line
- `NR>1 && a~/key1/ && !/key2/` skip first block and test if previous block contains `key1` and current line does not contain `key2`, then
- - `print "# Comment 2\nkey2=value2"` add new block
- `1;` is always true, so it will print all line.
- `a=$0` store line in variable `a` to use for test in next line

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `i` are tough to inline.

So this just uses `s///` replacement and `&` for the match data.  In other words, `s/.*/&\n.../` where `...` is your appended strings.

`sed -i '/key1/s/.*/&\n# Comment 2\nkey2=value2/' es-service`

Alternately:

You can use `s///e` to construct a shell command to generate output to be placed in the stream.

`sed -i '/key1/s/.*/printf "&\n# Comment 2\nkey2=value2\n"/e' es-service`

So I'm replacing `.*` with `printf "&\n` followed by what you'd like to insert.

`e` then executes the printf and sticks the output in the stream. I thought `e` was GNU-sed-only, but it's working for me with `--posix`.